# Uncaught system exception: signal 11

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Some of my users reported that sometimes they're getting the above error. Unfortunately I can't tell anything from the log file. Probably somewhere in code an object is over-released. Can I somehow catch it and log it?

Normally I'd go with Instruments and NSZobieEnabled but unfortunately it doesn't happen on my machine. Is there any chance to log the object?

```
1   ExceptionHandling                   0x00000001000879e2 -[NSExceptionHandler _handleException:mask:] + 168
    2   ExceptionHandling                   0x00000001000877ba NSExceptionHandlerUncaughtSignalHandler + 35
    3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff9836d8ea _sigtramp + 26
    4   ???                                 0x0000000001440013 0x0 + 21233683
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff985b525f -[NSArray initWithArray:range:copyItems:] + 591
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff94a193f3 recursivelyEncodeInvalidPersistentState + 1118
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff94a194a6 recursivelyEncodeInvalidPersistentState + 1297
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff94a194a6 recursivelyEncodeInvalidPersistentState + 1297
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff94a194a6 recursivelyEncodeInvalidPersistentState + 1297
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff94a194a6 recursivelyEncodeInvalidPersistentState + 1297
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff94a178aa -[NSPersistentUIManager flushAllChangesOptionallyWaitingUntilDone:updatingSnapshots:] + 1037
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff94a17467 -[NSPersistentUIManager flushPersistentStateAndClose:waitingUntilDone:] + 180
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff94a7eba5 -[NSApplication terminate:] + 1701
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff94aa357e -[NSApplication _terminateFromSender:askIfShouldTerminate:saveWindows:] + 280
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff94aad4a2 __52-[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEQuit]_block_invoke_0 + 46
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8bd9af01 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8bd970b6 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8bd9c0c8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 275
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff985a20fe __CFRunLoopRun + 1614
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff985a16b2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
    21  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff93fbf0a4 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209
    22  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff93fbed84 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 166
    23  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff93fbecd3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff94858613 _DPSNextEvent + 685
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fff94857ed2 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
    26  AppKit                              0x00007fff9484f283 -[NSApplication run] + 517
    27  AppKit                              0x00007fff947f3cb6 NSApplicationMain + 869
```

Answer (score 2):

Signal 11 means you have a segmentation fault somewhere...
So it may be related to something else than an Objective-C object, as in this case, you would more likely have an exception (even if a segfault may also happen).

So `NSZombieEnabled` won't help here.

Try to learn about signal handing in C. You can define a handler for the signal 11 (**SIGSEGV**), so you will be able to log a few things.

(Very) Basically:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void __handler( int sig );
static void __handler( int sig )
{
    /* Debug... */

    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

int main( void )
{
    signal( SIGSEGV, __handler );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What info can I exactly debug and log here?

Comment: Not much, but at least you can put a breakpoint on the signal handler, and debug from there.